# How to convert from lists to json in python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, nested

The required output of my nested loops is json, how to get there?

The input list structure looks like list = [[name, version, id],[name, version, id], ...]

```
list_1 = [
['mipl-abnd','v1.0.2','eelp234'],
['mipl-avfd','v1.1.5','32fv423'],
['mipl-awsd','v9.0.2','234eelp'],
['mipl-tgfd','v3.0.0','124fdge'],
['mipl-hrdss','v1.0.2','543rfd3'],
['mipl-oldss','v1.0.2','eelp234']] 

list_2 = [
['mipl-abnd','v1.0.2','eelp234'],
['mipl-avfd','v1.1.6','3254323'],
['mipl-awsd','v9.0.2','234eelp'],
['mipl-tgfd','v3.0.0','124fdge'],
['mipl-hrdss','v1.0.2','543rfd3'],
['mipl-newss','v1.0.2','eelp234']]
```

This is the code I used to get a final list:

```
def get_difference(l1,l2):
    l1 = get_ordered_list(file1.read())     
    l2 = get_ordered_list(file2.read()) 

    d1 = {k:[v1,v2] for k,v1,v2 in l1}
    d2 = {k:[v1,v2] for k,v1,v2 in l2}
    result = []
    for k,v in d2.items():
        if k in d1:
            v1 = d1[k]
            if v1[0] != v[0]:
                result.append({k,v1[0],v[0], v1[1],v[1]})
        else:
            result.append({k,'new',v[0],'new', v[1]})

    for k,v in d1.items():
        if k not in d2:
            result.append({k,v[0],'deprecated', v[1], 'deprecated'})
    
    res_json = json.dumps(result)
    return res_json
```

Current Output :

```
result = [['mipl-avfd', 'v1.1.5', 'v1.1.6','32fv423', '3254323'], ['mipl-oldss','v1.0.2', 'deprecated','eelp234', 'deprecated'], ['mipl-newss', 'new','v1.0.2','new', 'eelp234']]
```

Required Output(I want to write it to an easily readable JSON which can be later made into a table) :

```
{diff = {"name" : "mipl-avfd", 
         "old-version" : "v1.1.5", 
         "new-version" : "v1.1.6",
         "old-id" : "32fv423",
         "new-id" : "3254323"
         }, 
         {"name" : "mipl-oldss", 
         "old-version" : "v1.0.2", 
         "new-version" : "deprecated",
         "old-id" : "eelp234",
         "new-id" : "deprecated"
         },
         {"name" : "mipl-newss", 
         "old-version" : "new", 
         "new-version" : "v1.0.2",
         "old-id" : "eelp234",
         "new-id" : "new"
         }

}
```

Comment: `{k,v1[0],v[0], v1[1],v[1]}` and all constructs like this create _sets_, not dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question right. You have "old" `list_1` and "new" `list_2` and you want to construct flat list how the versions change (I assume, in `list_1` you have old versions):

```
import json
from itertools import groupby


list_1 = [
['mipl-abnd','v1.0.2','eelp234'],
['mipl-avfd','v1.1.5','32fv423'],
['mipl-awsd','v9.0.2','234eelp'],
['mipl-tgfd','v3.0.0','124fdge'],
['mipl-hrdss','v1.0.2','543rfd3'],
['mipl-oldss','v1.0.2','eelp234']]

list_2 = [
['mipl-abnd','v1.0.2','eelp234'],
['mipl-avfd','v1.1.6','3254323'],
['mipl-awsd','v9.0.2','234eelp'],
['mipl-tgfd','v3.0.0','124fdge'],
['mipl-hrdss','v1.0.2','543rfd3'],
['mipl-newss','v1.0.2','eelp234']]


s = sorted(list_1 + list_2, key=lambda k: k[0])

out = []
for v, g in groupby(s, lambda k: k[0]):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g) == 2:
        out.append({
            'name': v,
            'old-version': g[0][1],
            'new-version': g[1][1],
            'old-id': g[0][2],
            'new-id': g[1][2],
        })
    else:
        if g[0] in list_1:
            out.append({
                'name': v,
                'old-version': g[0][1],
                'new-version': 'deprecated',
                'old-id': g[0][2],
                'new-id': 'deprecated',
            })
        else:
            out.append({
                'name': v,
                'old-version': 'new',
                'new-version': g[0][1],
                'old-id': 'new',
                'new-id': g[0][2],
            })

print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "name": "mipl-abnd",
        "old-version": "v1.0.2",
        "new-version": "v1.0.2",
        "old-id": "eelp234",
        "new-id": "eelp234"
    },
    {
        "name": "mipl-avfd",
        "old-version": "v1.1.5",
        "new-version": "v1.1.6",
        "old-id": "32fv423",
        "new-id": "3254323"
    },
    {
        "name": "mipl-awsd",
        "old-version": "v9.0.2",
        "new-version": "v9.0.2",
        "old-id": "234eelp",
        "new-id": "234eelp"
    },
    {
        "name": "mipl-hrdss",
        "old-version": "v1.0.2",
        "new-version": "v1.0.2",
        "old-id": "543rfd3",
        "new-id": "543rfd3"
    },
    {
        "name": "mipl-newss",
        "old-version": "new",
        "new-version": "v1.0.2",
        "old-id": "new",
        "new-id": "eelp234"
    },
    {
        "name": "mipl-oldss",
        "old-version": "v1.0.2",
        "new-version": "deprecated",
        "old-id": "eelp234",
        "new-id": "deprecated"
    },
    {
        "name": "mipl-tgfd",
        "old-version": "v3.0.0",
        "new-version": "v3.0.0",
        "old-id": "124fdge",
        "new-id": "124fdge"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What you said is a json is not a valid json. Also, json is a string - you want a dict structure. You don't have to dump it into a json string.
2. Why do you give l1 and l2 as arguments to the function when you overwrite them in the first lines?
3. file1 and file2 are not defined in the function. Also, for reading files you should use `with` to properly close the file.

---

First, you need to declare the keys (labels) somewhere:

```
keys = ["name", "old-version", "old-id", "new-id"]
```

Then, instead of appending a list, you append a dict.

Thankfully, dicts can be easily made from lists of tuples - and we can merge keys and your current lists into lists of tuples easily, e.g.:

```
dict(zip(keys, [k,v1[0],v[0], v1[1],v[1]]))
```

So it now looks like this:

```
    for k,v in d2.items():
        if k in d1:
            v1 = d1[k]
            if v1[0] != v[0]:
                result.append(dict(zip(keys, [k,v1[0],v[0], v1[1],v[1]])))
        else:
            result.append(dict(zip(keys, [k,'new',v[0],'new', v[1]])))
    for k,v in d1.items():
        if k not in d2:
            result.append(dict(zip(keys, [k,v[0],'deprecated', v[1], 'deprecated'])))
```